# Access to ESXI using Ansible (python)

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, python, ansible

I'm want to execute a command using Ansible on an remote ESXi but it seems that a module grp is missing.

```
# ansible esxi -a "date"
esxi | FAILED >> {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"//.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1409770903.88-199403044644009/command\", line 229, in <module>\r\n    import grp\r\nImportError: No module named grp\r\n", 
    "parsed": false
}
```

I tried to copy theses modules from another host to the ESXi python lib folder but it didn't work either. Is there a way to make it work or should I try to compile a newer version of Python for ESXi ?

Comment: ESXi isn't something that an administrator should be attempting to install package upgrades to. it's not Linux, even though the service console looks like it a little bit. If you want to manage an ESXi machine properly, do it through vSphere which does offer some command-line options. I'm familiar with PowerCLI on Windows, I'm not sure of their management ecosystem from Linux/Unix workstations.

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the -m raw option because python-simplejson isn't installed on ESXi.

```
# ansible esxi -m raw -a "date"
esx1 | success | rc=0 >>
Sun Aug 24 22:26:49 UTC 2014
```